# determine optimal cut-off value for data (in matlab)

Tags: algorithm, matlab, statistics

I realize this is an unspecific question (because I don't know a lot about the topic, please help me in this regard), that said here's the task I'd like to achieve:

Find a statistically sound algorithm to determine an optimal cut-off value to binarize a vector to filter out minimal values (i.e. get rid of). Here's code in matlab to visualize this problem:

```
randomdata=rand(1,100,1);
figure;plot(randomdata); %plot random data between 0 and 1
cutoff=0.5; %plot cut-off value
line(get(gca,'xlim'),[cutoff cutoff],'Color','red');
```

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could try using Matlab's percentile function:

```
 cutoff = prctile(randomdata,10);
```

[image: lowCutOffPlot]